# Deleting all columns with less than 6 decimals in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

I want to delete all columns with less than 6 decimals in a pandas dataframe. I've tried filling columns with less than 6 decimals with 0's by pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.6f}'.format but this is only for displaying the float. So is there a way to either fill the actual values in the dataframe up to 6 decimals with 0's (such that it shows in the csv file) or to delete all columns with less than 6 decimals.

Comment: Please post a small extract of the dataframe as an example

Comment: There are instances with 5.673947 and there are instances with 10.0 so I want to either delete the columns with 10.0 values or fill those up

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, there is a way to format the floating point values in the dataframe while exporting to a csv file. This can be achieved by passing the optional parameter `float_format` to `DataFrame.to_csv` method.

```
df.to_csv(filepath, index=False, float_format='%.6f')
```